# Trying to keep wp sidebars on the same line

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add 3 widgets to my WordPress theme. I know how to add widgets and I already have them on site, but the problem is that each show up on a different line. This is the code that I'm using:

```
<center><?php echo do_shortcode( '[otw_is sidebar=otw-sidebar-2] [otw_is sidebar=otw-sidebar-3] [otw_is sidebar=otw-sidebar-1]' ); ?>
<?php } ?> </center>
```

any ideas how I can align them somehow that they all show on the same line and in center?

- these 3 = [otw_is sidebar=otw-sidebar-2] [otw_is sidebar=otw-sidebar-3] [otw_is sidebar=otw-sidebar-1] are my widget shortcuts.

regards

Comment: probably you want to use `float:left` css property on all the elements created by those shortcodes.

Comment: As far as I know OTW Sidebars is a not a free plugin. Why don't you ask them for help? They'll be happy to help a customer. Besides, I'm pretty sure you don't have hack your way into code, they already should have classes and methods for vertical/horizontal display of widgets.